# How to remove all the subviews and the nesting of the a view while removing the a UIView from superview?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I am developing a simple UI control. The data source can be any one. UI Control I  develop will receive any thing derived from UIVIew using the data source methods and will add in its view.

Now I will be able to track all the UIViews I receive from the data source using a collection. When I use the below statement, all the views will be removed from the superview.

```
 [gridCells makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

What will happen to all the views that were added on the views created and added on the view returned through the data source methods?

Comment: check this [article](http://nearthespeedoflight.com/article/how_does_uiview_-removefromsuperview_work_and_what_does_it_mean_for_objective-c_s_inheritence_model_)

Comment: reading it..Interesting..one

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all the subviews of superview like this.

```
 for (UIView *subview in self.view)
  {
     [subview removeFromSuperview];
  }
```